# Different indent on loop identifiers in MonoDevelop

Tags: loops, monodevelop, d, indentation

Is there a way to stop MonoDevelop de-indenting Loop Identifiers by one step? I'm writing in D using MonoDevelop 5.0.1 with Mono-D 2.1.9 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Whenever I give a loop an identifier so it can be broken or continued in another nested loop it always de-indents the line with the loop statement by one step, breaking consistency with everything else. This probably looks much better if you but braces on newlines but I don't and I'm not about to change my entire workflow for one annoying formatting quirk.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

```
void functionName() {
    dosomething();
    foreach(Object o; array1) { //<- indents correctly if it doesn't have an identifier
        o.dosomethng();
    }
outer: foreach(Object o; array2) { //<- always indents one step back if identifier present
        o.dosomething();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to disable the behaviour? Nothing in Edit->Preferences->Code Formatting seems to say anything about it either for D or C#

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug in Mono-D AddIn probably somewhere inside this code: https://github.com/aBothe/Mono-D/blob/master/MonoDevelop.DBinding/Formatting/Indentation/DTextEditorIndentation.cs

I suggest you to report bug on Mono-D AddIn issue tracker at https://github.com/aBothe/Mono-D/issues or checkout Mono-D AddIn source code fix bug and make pull request. ;)